# Flex SpringGraph in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

How can I have the same effect as of http://mark-shepherd.com/SpringGraph/RoamerDemo/bin/RoamerDemo.html using only actionscript?

Comment: Which effect were you looking to create?  Do you realize that the Flex Framework is built in ActionScript?  Whatever effect you want to replicate already is done with "Only ActionScript".  It may have dependencies to the Flex Framework, though.  Have you tried looking at the code behind the demo / component?

Comment: I would like to achieve the spring effect. Yes, I have seen that within flex's MXML, actionscript exists. But I don't want to use Flex and that's why I would like to achieve it only using actionscript. I googled a lot but did not found any info on usage of mark-shepherd's SPRING-GRAPH libray for using only in actionscript.

Comment: I don't think you understood my point.  The Flex Framework is 100% ActionScript.  MXML is just an "ActionScript Code Generation Language" and the Flex Compiler turns ActionSCript into MXML.  You can get at the ActionScript code for any MXML sample by using the '-keep' argument when you compile.  It may not be practical to make the code Flex Framework independent; but that doesn't mean it isn't ActionScript.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented the same algorythm of graph nodes aligment a few years ago in http://kachurovskiy.com/f/p/dmvow/DMVoW.html . You can find the source code at http://code.google.com/p/dmvow/ although it's not so simple to extract the layout code.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have downloaded the Mark Shepherd code and examples but examples are based on FLEX framework.